# Segmented list for contacts based on outcome for users imported through xConnect client

Tags: xconnect, segmented-list, interaction, outcomes

Sitecore 9.0.2

Hi All,
I am trying to add an (out-of-box) outcome to xDB for real-time users and from historical data (a csv file).

For real-time users, I am using Tracker to add the outcome. The outcomes in this scenario are getting added to the table `[ContactFacets]` against `FacetKey` `InteractionsCache` along with the date and value.

For historical users, I am using the xConnect client. The outcome in such a scenario is getting updated under the table `[Interactions]` but not in the table `[ContactFacets]`.

I tried to create a segmented list using the inbuilt rules to filter the contacts, I am only getting the contacts who are registered in real-time. I want to see the contacts from the historical data.

What I am missing here?

Comment: How exactly are you using xConnect client to register outcomes for historical users? I'm assuming that you follow this guid: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/add-interaction-events.html

Comment: @grg: Yes, I am using the same set of code just different outcome Id, timestamp, currency and value.

Comment: Is new interactions successfully created for historical users?

Comment: @grg: I just have this facet data for facetkey 'InteractionsCache': {"@odata.type":"#Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.Cache.InteractionsCache","InteractionCaches":[],"DeviceVendorHardwareModels":[],"DeviceTypes":[],"DeviceVendors":[],"AreaCodes":[],"BusinessNames":[],"Cities":[],"Countries":[],"Dns":[],"Isps":[],"MetroCodes":[],"PostalCodes":[],"Regions":[],"Referrers":[],"SearchKeywords":[]}

Comment: Have you triple checked the interactions are being posted to the contact you expect?

Comment: @eglasius: They are getting updated under interactions table. 100 % sure.